# Create a Live Audio Streaming Service with Icecast and Drupal

Tags: web, drupal, streaming, icecast, internet-radio

I want to develop a Web Radio. To do this, to make good Radio Show I need:

- **RadioDJ**: to doing stuff with Jingles, Speakers, Songs
- **IceCast Client**: to broadcast audio streaming to IceCast Server, like BUTT (broadcast using this tool)
- **IceCast Server**: to stream live audio multimedia content
- **WebSite**: I think about a WebSite hosted on the same machine where there is Icecast Server, but I don't know if use Apache or Nginx as WebServer. On this WebServer I will put the CMS Drupal.

With Drupal I want to build a WebSite that can make available all old streams, like take it from RSS or directly from a directory inside the OS. 
With IceCast I can stream audio in live, and store this stream in a file and put it in a directory. What I want is "mapping" this file to be viewed on Drupal website.
How can I do that ?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Icecast doesn't keep the stream around, so you either need something to record the stream from Icecast or you need a separate encoder to write files to disk as you go.

Comment: I use icecast recently and from the file icecast.conf you can set up what he calls "dump-file" where you can put a path and the name of the dump file can be formated with strftime of bash, so you can store the stream each time you open and close a mount point or close connection from the icecast client